# How to integrate the sentiment analysis script with the chatbot for analysing the user's reply in the same console screen?

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, chatbot, sentiment-analysis, nltk-trainer

I want to make a chatbot that uses Sentiment analyser script for knowing the sentiment of the user's reply for which I have completed the Chatbot making.

Now only thing I want to do is to use this Script to analyse the reply of user using the chatbot that I have made.
How should I integrate this **sentiment_analysis.py** script with the **chatbot.py** file to analyse the sentiment's of user?

**Update:**
**The overall performance will be like this :**
*Chatbot: How was your day?

User: It was an awesome day. I feel so elated and motivated today.

User Reply: Positive

Sentiment score = (some random value)*
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate your code since there are few dependency files. But I feel that you can solve this by importing sentiments analyse classes to chat bot script.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem I am facing **Importing sentiment analysis classes to chat bot script** any sort of guidance you may provide.

Comment: Okay. I will try to add some code snippets and I can guide you to do it. But I can't execute and check for correctness due to dependency issues.

Comment: @Mufeed, Thank you so much.

Comment: what does label: 'text' in sentiment analysis script do?

Comment: Do your sentiment_analysis.py run as desired?

Comment: Sorry, label: text is not a part , please see the updated script.  Yes it does run properly. If you want i can give my github link.

Comment: Please share your github link

Comment: I added a code. Try to run it and let me know if you get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import classes from sentiment analysis script to chatbot script. Then do necessary things according to your requirement. For example. I modified your chatbot script:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from sentiment_analysis import Splitter, POSTagger, DictionaryTagger  # import all the classes from sentiment_analysis
import os

bot = ChatBot('Bot')
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

# for files in os.listdir('C:/Users/username\Desktop\chatterbot\chatterbot_corpus\data/english/'):
# data = open('C:/Users/username\Desktop\chatterbot\chatterbot_corpus\data/english/' + files, 'r').readlines()
data = [
    "My name is Tony",
    "that's a good name",
    "Thank you",
    "How you doing?",
    "I am Fine. What about you?",
    "I am also fine. Thanks for asking."]

bot.train(data)

# I included 3 functions from sentiment_analysis here for ease of loading. Alternatively you can create a class for them in sentiment_analysis.py and import here.
def value_of(sentiment):
    if sentiment == 'positive': return 1
    if sentiment == 'negative': return -1
    return 0

def sentence_score(sentence_tokens, previous_token, acum_score):
    if not sentence_tokens:
        return acum_score
    else:
        current_token = sentence_tokens[0]
        tags = current_token[2]
        token_score = sum([value_of(tag) for tag in tags])
        if previous_token is not None:
            previous_tags = previous_token[2]
            if 'inc' in previous_tags:
                token_score *= 2.0
            elif 'dec' in previous_tags:
                token_score /= 2.0
            elif 'inv' in previous_tags:
                token_score *= -1.0
        return sentence_score(sentence_tokens[1:], current_token, acum_score + token_score)

def sentiment_score(review):
    return sum([sentence_score(sentence, None, 0.0) for sentence in review])

# create instances of all classes
splitter = Splitter()
postagger = POSTagger()
dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'dicts/positive.yml', 'dicts/negative.yml',
                            'dicts/inc.yml', 'dicts/dec.yml', 'dicts/inv.yml'])

print("ChatBot is Ready...")
print("ChatBot : Welcome to my world! What is your name?")
message = input("you: ")
print("\n")

while True:
    if message.strip() != 'Bye'.lower():

        reply = bot.get_response(message)

        # process the text
        splitted_sentences = splitter.split(message)
        pos_tagged_sentences = postagger.pos_tag(splitted_sentences)
        dict_tagged_sentences = dicttagger.tag(pos_tagged_sentences)

        # find sentiment score
        score = sentiment_score(dict_tagged_sentences)

        if (score >= 1):
            print('User Reply: Positive')
        else:
            print('User Reply: Negative')

        print("Sentiment score :",score)
        print('ChatBot:',reply)

    if message.strip() == 'Bye'.lower():
        print('ChatBot: Bye')
        break
    message = input("you: ")
    print("\n")
```

Let me know when you get errors.

Comment: This code is working fine after I ran with  necessary files on my machine.

Comment: Yes, it is wroking well.Just a lil' bit issue.The Bold Part is asking so many question on the go:  
    'ChatBot is Ready...
ChatBot : Welcome to my world! What is your name?
you: Tony. Thank You


User Reply: Positive
Sentiment score : 1.0
**ChatBot: How you doing?I am Fine. What about you?I am also fine. Thanks for asking.**
you: I am doing great.


User Reply: Positive
Sentiment score : 1.0
ChatBot: that's a good name
you: You are so bad Bot.


User Reply: Negative
Sentiment score : -1.0
ChatBot: that's a good name
you: No, I have a bad feeling'

Comment: Problem with training data. I updated the code. Please check it

Comment: The problem was we added a bunch of dialogues without comma and trained it. I modified the code by adding comma. You need to delete the old db file and retrain after adding comma. Problem will be slved.

Comment: Yes now it works very well.  Thank you.  But how does it make the database using 'Sqlite Alchemy' or any other?  
Another question is I want the chatbot's response as "That's a good  name." after any name. How is that possible?

Comment: You can go through https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/storage/index.html to get some ideas about integrating other dbs. I don't have enough knowledge to answer your second question. I will go through the docs and let you know if I get anything to help you.

Comment: Sure I will go through this doc. Thanks for being helpful always.

Comment: One question though : What Libraries are required for above code and is there a way to know using cmd?

Comment: You mean the code I posted here or the code you want to create in future?

Comment: The code you posted here. I have to note down all the libraries that i have used here for later reference.

Comment: Please tell me what libraries have been used asap. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Main libraries - Nltk, chatterbot, mostly we use sklearn too, other common libraries - os,sys. If you want you can use Tensorflow too

Comment: Could you please help me with the backend database that is being created as dbsqlite to be converted in csv automatically, can you please some method or any API?

Comment: What you want to store in your csv?

Comment: When I run my above chatbot code, it creates a backend dbsqlite3 file. I want to convert that dbsqlite3 file to .csv file on its own.

Comment: I am working on it. I will let you know if I succeed :)

Comment: Okay. Make it possile asap. Thank you life saviour

Comment: Hy, Sorry for the delay. I had some other work to do. I analysed the database file. There are multiple tables in it. You want to create a csv file for each?

Comment: Here I am back to ask for your help! I was thinking to make a plugin for my chatbot. Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed and make that implementable?

Comment: Well. Please be specific. I didn't quiet understand your requirement.

Comment: i want this chatbot to be runnable from any browser. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can convert your chat bot to a simple web application using Flask framework.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Which machine learning approach have been used in the above Code?